# xslt replace a node

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml

```
<ApplicationInsights xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ApplicationInsights/2013/Settings">
<InstrumentationKey>xxx-yuyu</InstrumentationKey>
</ApplicationInsights>
```

I have an xslt

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="InstrumentationKey">
    <InstrumentationKey>BBB</InstrumentationKey>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

This just will not replace InstrumentationKey.  It only works when I remove xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ApplicationInsights/2013/Settings" from the ApplicationInsights.

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I'm closing this as a duplicate because the same question comes up so often. Don't take that amiss; it's an elephant trap in the language and you can't be expected to know that everyone else is falling into the same trap. For other answers, just search for "XSLT default namespace".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle namespaces properly.
Check it out the following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ApplicationInsights/2013/Settings" exclude-result-prefixes="ns2">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ns2:InstrumentationKey">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
            <xsl:text>BBB</xsl:text>
        </xsl:element>
        <!--<InstrumentationKey>BBB</InstrumentationKey>-->
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```